# How to link up my GeoServer layers with my standalone geowebcache instance

Tags: geoserver, xml, geowebcache

How do I get my GeoServer layers show up on the demo page of gwc. Do I have to edit the config XML manually for each layer?

Comment: No, you shouldn't do it manually. You can follow this [guide](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/quickstart/index.html#view-preconfigured-layers). Check for view layers from WMS.